# Select Query with Date Range and single Date in 2 separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have single table, 1 date column and I need to count entries for single date and also month to date in separate columns.

Result should be like:

```
Locations     |  Today's Count |  Mth to Date

 Site 1       |       72       |     475
 Site 2       |       61       |     341
 Site 3       |       10       |     179
```

So far I've tried:

```
SELECT 
    A.SITENAME, 
    COUNT(A.SALEID) AS 'TODAY'S COUNT',
    COUNT(M.SALEID) AS 'MTH to DATE'
FROM SALESDATA AS A 
LEFT JOIN SALESDATA as M on 
    M.SALEID = A.SALEID AND 
    M.SALEID BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE()) AND
    DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE())
WHERE (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, A.SALEDATE), 0) >= DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY A.SITENAME
```

also:

```
SELECT 
    A.SITENAME, 
    COUNT(D.SALEID) AS 'TODAY'S COUNT',
   COUNT(M.SALEID) AS 'MTH to DATE'
FROM SALESDATA AS A 
LEFT JOIN SALESDATA as M on 
    M.SALEID = A.SALEID AND 
    M.SALEID BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE()) AND
    DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE())
LEFT JOIN SALESDATA as D on 
    D.SALEID = A.SALEID AND
    D.SALEID AND
    (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, A.SALEDATE), 0) >= DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY A.SITENAME
```

I get this:

```
Locations     |  Today's Count |  Mth to Date

 Site 1       |       72       |     0
 Site 2       |       61       |     0
 Site 3       |       10       |     0
```

Also tried using `CASE`, but I really had no clue there.

Any help would be most appreciative.

Comment: example data would be nice

Comment: Are you *sure* that code is working? `COUNT(A.SALEID) AS 'TODAY'S COUNT',` would cause an error (`Incorrect syntax near 's'.`), so you wouldn't get any results. Generally it's best to avoid names (objects and aliases) that require delimit identifying and get the presentation layer to make them more "wordy". and it's also preferred to not use single quotes (`'`) to delimit identify them, as single quotes are used for literal strings. Stick to brackets (`[]`) in T-SQL, or double quotes (`"`) if you ensure that `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is always set to `ON`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use Window functions here - after all, you can use them in a subquery and aggregate them as desired. By this you can calculate the total count per month as well as a floating value where you see the impact of the days count on the monthly total.

Here an example:

```
CREATE TABLE TestData (
  MySite NVARCHAR(10)
  ,MyDate date
  ,MyVal int
 )
GO

INSERT INTO TestData VALUES
('Site 1', '2020-08-01', 1)
,('Site 1', '2020-08-02', 1)
,('Site 1', '2020-08-03', 1)
,('Site 1', '2020-09-01', 1)
,('Site 1', '2020-09-02', 1)
,('Site 1', '2020-09-03', 1)
,('Site 1', '2020-09-04', 1)
,('Site 2', '2020-08-03', 1)
,('Site 2', '2020-09-01', 1)
,('Site 2', '2020-09-02', 1)
GO

SELECT MySite
      ,MyDate
      ,COUNT(MyVal) OVER (PARTITION BY MySite, MyDate) CntToday
      ,COUNT(MyVal) OVER (PARTITION BY MySite, YEAR(MyDate)*100+MONTH(MyDate)) CntMonthTotal
      ,COUNT(MyVal) OVER (PARTITION BY MySite, YEAR(MyDate)*100+MONTH(MyDate) ORDER BY MyDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) CntMonthFloating
  FROM TestData
```

See fiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/82827/9/1

Answer (score 0):

```
select
sitename
,count(case when saledate = convert(date,getdate()) then distinct saleId end) sales_today
,count(case when month(SALEDATE) = 09 and year(SALEDATE) = 2020 then distinct saleId end) sales_month
from SALESDATA 
group by
sitename
```

Ideally could do with a bit more insight into the dataset you are working with. Not sure why you are joining your table onto itself either.

Also you where clause only includes today and yesterdays sales data as you've done today and today - 1 date, so you will never get the months data.

to make it more dynamic and reusable you can just pass years and months into two separate variables and then use them in place of the static when clauses in the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT s.SITENAME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.saledate >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as todays_cnt,
       COUNT(*) as month_to_date 
FROM SALESDATA s
WHERE saledate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)
GROUP BY s.SITENAME
```